# Add folders under src, and show them in project view

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I found that the famous open source example "u2020" has so many folders under src, and I can see them in the project view.

Source: https://github.com/JakeWharton/u2020

Screenshot:

[image]

To archive this in my project, I tried to make folders named "internal", "internalDebug", etc... but Android studio does not show them automatically.

I also tried to open and find the keyword "internalDebug" in u2020's build.gradle, but there is no such keyword.

How can I archive this? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found answer. It was "productFlavors".
It is kind of build option that you can add new files to project. (Same file name is not allowed, it conflicts)

Details: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html

Source: https://github.com/JakeWharton/u2020/blob/master/build.gradle

```
  productFlavors {
      internal {
          applicationId 'com.jakewharton.u2020.internal'
      }
      production {
          applicationId 'com.jakewharton.u2020'
      }
  }
```

Each flavors can have additional folders that has suffix "Release" or "Debug".

For example, if you define flavor "foo", real folder structure can be:

src
     - foo
     - fooDebug
     - fooRelease
     - main  <= Your original source here
     - test

Comment: It is strange, but I can see only one flavor in project tree view. Also, i can't see "fooRelease" in project tree view.